# Why am I missing a video from my 'liked' playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have 'liked' 1000 YouTube videos but my 'liked' playlist only lists 999.

I can confirm it was 1000 because I took a screenshot last week.

I only access Gmail from my phone, my Google account is secured using 2FA (Authenticator) and no third-party apps have access to my account.

Why am I missing a video?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the video you 'liked' was deleted.  The owner could have deleted it or it may have been removed by YouTube for a policy violation.

When YouTube videos are removed, all flags, 'likes', 'dislikes', 'commented', and 'downloaded', are also removed.